# Excel creates a new file when launching which is 'dirty' (prompts for saving changes)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I recently reinstalled Office 2016 (64 bit). Since doing so, Excel now has the following annoying behavior:

- Each time Excel is started, it creates/displays a new blank workbook.
- Even though I have made no changes to the new workbook, I am prompted
  to save changes when I attempt to close it.

This even happens when Excel is only being used as a preview handler (e.g. in Directory Opus).

Answer (score 1):

This problem was resolved after I disabled/uninstalled the following COM add-in:

MySQL For Excel 1.3.7 by Oracle